# Why doesn't any event work in dynamically loaded code?

Tags: javascript

I load an HTML page inside a modal

When I put the code out of the modal, the event works ( click, input, and others )

NOTE: I don't use and I don't want to use JQuery ( never )

Demo: https://codepen.io/jonathan_silva/pen/vYKqrvE?editors=0010

I've been trying to make it work for 3 days. It looks like everything is fine but...

Help me

```
const codeHTML = () => {
    const code = `
        <div id="page">
            <div class="steps">
                <article class="step1">
                    <div class="options-grid">
                        <div class="select-box">
                            <div class="options business-options">
                                <div class="business-option">
                                    <input type="radio" class="radio" />
                                    <label>Business A</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="business-option">
                                    <input type="radio" class="radio" />
                                    <label>Business B</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="business-option">
                                    <input type="radio" class="radio" />
                                    <label>Business C</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="select-business">Select Business</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;

    return code;
}

/* MODAL */
const modal = async ({ target }) => {  
    const html = codeHTML(); // Load HTML page

    let section = document.getElementById('modal-page');

    if (!section) {
        return;
    }

    document.getElementById('modal-content').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);

    section.classList.add('modal');

    const onSectionClick = ({ target }) => {
        if (!target.classList.contains('modal-close')) {
            return;
        }

        section.classList.remove('modal');

        section.removeEventListener('click', onSectionClick);

        document.querySelector('#page').remove();
    }

    section.addEventListener('click', onSectionClick);
}

const openModal = document.querySelector('.announce a');
openModal.addEventListener('click', event => modal(event));

/* SELECT */
const selectBusiness = document.querySelector('.select-business');
const businessContainer = document.querySelector('.business-options');
const optionsBusiness = document.querySelectorAll('.business-option');

if (selectBusiness !== null) {
  selectBusiness.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log(e); // Nothing happens
    businessContainer.classList.toggle("active");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements you're trying to `querySelector` aren't there when you call `querySelector`, since you only add them to the DOM within the `modal()` function. (You can do e.g. `console.log(selectBusiness)` to see that with your own eyes.)

You'll need to move that event binding in there, after the `insertAdjacentHTML` call.